# Query Combinaton

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to build a query using asp.net core c#

https://www.reflectionit.nl/blog/2017/paging-in-asp-net-core-mvc-and-entityframework-core

I trying to do a filtering however I need the data from another table which have my unique id

```
var result = _context.UserRoles.Where(y => y.RoleId.Contains(selectedRoles.Id)); // Retrieve the the userid i have from another table with the selected roleid

var query = _context.Users.Where(x => //I have already tried contains, where join );
```

If there is a site where i can learn this query please recommend. "Join()" does not work as I am doing paging

Comment: Your requirement is not clear! Explain clearly what you are actually wanting!

Answer (score 0):

a least two solutions (please note that I do not check the identity classes members, so the following is the "spirit" of the solution (**you miss the select** clauses) ):

```
var result = _context.UserRoles.
    Where(y => selectedRoles.Contains(y.RoleId)).
    Select(y => y.User);
```

or

```
var result = _context.UserRoles.
     Where(y => selectedRoles.Contains(y.RoleId)).
     Select(y => y.UserId); 
query = _context.Users.
    Where(x => result.Contains(x.Id));
```

That said, assuming that there is no `UserRoles` table exposed in Identity (v2), you probably want:

```
userManager.Users.
    Where(u => u.Roles.Any(r => selectecRoles.Contains(r.RoleId)));
```

Up to you to instanciate the userManager.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Can i know why can't i put the select first instead of where?
Do you have any link for me to reference this entity framework sql statement